# How to prevent users accessing other users files?

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, php

First of all I want to mention, that I am fairly new to ubuntu server and apache and all that stuff, so please have mercy :)

So my problem is, that I am creating a folder for each user on my website (the website is mass-downloading images so the user can download the zip and later on its being deleted). So I have my `/var/www/html` directory where I keep my index.php and all that stuff and the folder `Download` in which the user will get their own folder for a short period of time(~2Hours).

Obviously it's not hard for the user to see, that there is the "Download" folder where every other user has his images in, so how can I prevent Users from accessing `/var/www/html/Downloads` but still get their images from `/var/www/html/Downloads/SomeUniqueID` ?

Comment: What sort of system is this? How are the users created? Are they been created within the server or using some web scripts... Would you please add more in detail as to what sort of process or services are you offering.

Comment: Ofcourse, the user does not need an account or anything. The user just inserts a link on my site and the program parses the website for images downloads them and puts them in the folder. I am working with the Ubuntu Server 14.04.

Comment: This seems more like programming than it is to do with Ubuntu.